# REST api using java for adding flows in ODL

Tags: java, rest, opendaylight

Can some1 tell me how to add flows using REST api using java in ODL?

I know basics of REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the REST API, as described here: 
https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_OpenFlow_Plugin:End_to_End_Flows